# Отображение stream video в QML

Tags: python, qt, qml, pyqt

Прошу помочь с решением вопроса на тему: отображение `stream video` в графике `QML`.

Есть `backend` который работает на `python`, и с использованием `opencv` получает и обрабатывает изображения, после чего выкладывает результаты в элемент Image на `QML`. На данный момент работает, но с тормозами. Как я понимаю скорее всего использую не правильный подход к отображению изображений и необходимо использовать элемент альтернативный `Image`(к примеру элемент `Video` ). У кого есть опыт в решении похожего вопроса, прошу вашего совета. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для решения такого рода задачи необходимо использовать элементы QML [VideoOutput](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtmultimedia-videooutput.html) и [Camera](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtmultimedia-camera.html), они позволяют отображать видеострим в реальном времени и если встаёт вопрос обработки видеопотока(каждого фрейма), то на этот случай у элемента VideoOutput есть возможность реализации [фильтров](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtMultimedia/QAbstractVideoFilter.html#PySide2.QtMultimedia.PySide2.QtMultimedia.QAbstractVideoFilter.createFilterRunnable) изображения. Но к сожалению на данный момент в PySide2 обнаружен [bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-785) касаемый разработки фильтров, надеюсь что в ближайшее время проблема будет решена.

В данный момент данную задачу я решил с использованием элементов QML Image и Timer.

```
property int current_i: 0

 Image {

            id: image
            anchors.rightMargin: 5
            anchors.leftMargin: 5
            anchors.bottomMargin: 5
            anchors.topMargin: 5
            anchors.fill: parent
            source: "image://from_python/" + current_i
            fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
        }
 Timer {
                interval: 1; running: true; repeat: true
                onTriggered: {
                    current_i = current_i + 1

                    if(current_i > 100){
                        current_i = 0
                    }
                }
            }
```

При изменении переменной `current_i` каждый раз вызывается ранее подгруженный класс наследуемый от [QQuickImageProvider](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickimageprovider.html), в котором вызывается перегруженная функция `requestImage` вызывающая функции opencv

```
class ImageProvider(QQuickImageProvider):

    def __init__(self):
        super(ImageProvider, self).__init__(QQuickImageProvider.Image)
        self.camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)


    def get_qimage(self, image):
        height, width, colors = image.shape
        bytesPerLine = 3 * width

        image = QImage(image.data,
                       width,
                       height,
                       bytesPerLine,
                       QImage.Format_RGB888)


        image = image.rgbSwapped()

        return image

    def requestImage(self, p_str, size):
        _,frame = self.camera.read()

        image = self.get_qimage(frame)

        return image,image.size()
```